# Tree Walks With Weighted Nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree

Given a tree, where the nodes have a value(can be negative), find the path that maximizes the sum of nodes in the path.

I have tried using to get a solution using Dynamic programming techniques, but can not break through.

Comment: In order to receive assistance on this site you will need to post some code

Answer (score 0):

We will do a flood-fill algorithm on the tree, starting from each leaf, and running the [maximum subsequence sum](http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-maximum-subsequence-problem) algorithm on the paths we discover during the flood-fill. This produces a candidate maximum value for each pair of leaves; and we choose the largest of these as our true answer. This solution takes O(n^2) time: there are O(n) leaves, and we do O(n) work to do a flood-fill version of the maximum-subsequence-sum problem on each leaf, yielding O(n^2) work total for the candidate production phase. We then do O(n^2) work to choose the maximal path out of the O(n^2) candidates we have generated.

I will give a sample implementation in Haskell. Some imports you can mostly ignore:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Monoid
```

For simplicity, we will represent our tree as the function which, given a node, tells the weight and what neighbors are available. When naming types and terms, I will use `w` for weights and `n` for nodes.

```
type Tree w n = n -> (w, [n])
```

It will be handy to have a way to refer to a path and its weight:

```
type WeightedPath w n = (Sum w, [n])
```

During our walk, we will keep two statistics, namely, the maximal path ending at the current node, and the maximal path we've seen so far. We'll also have a constant for the "empty summary" that corresponds to the empty tree: no paths, and zero weight.

```
data Summary w n = Summary
    { endingHere     :: WeightedPath w n
    , endingAnywhere :: WeightedPath w n
    }

emptySummary :: Num w => Summary w n
emptySummary = Summary mempty mempty
```

We'll need a flood-fill algorithm. It's pretty simple, though it is parameterized by an "initial summary" and a way to extend the summary by one extra weighted node; this is because we'll be using the flood-fill algorithm both to find all the leaves and to find candidate paths. One trick we'll need to watch for is to make sure that we don't back-track; we track the previous node (if any) in `nPrevious` for this purpose.

```
flood :: Eq n => (w -> n -> s -> s) -> s -> Tree w n -> n -> [s]
flood extend summary t = go Nothing summary where
    go nPrevious summary nCurrent = case maybe id delete nPrevious ns of
        [] -> [summary']
        ns -> ns >>= go (Just nCurrent) summary'
        where
        (w, ns)  = t nCurrent
        summary' = extend w nCurrent summary
```

For example, we can find all leaves by making our "summary" just be the last node we saw. If the tree is empty, we'll throw our hands up in disgust:

```
findLeaves :: Eq n => Tree w n -> n -> [n]
findLeaves = flood (\w n s -> n) undefined
```

We can extend a path candidate summary by one node as in the linked algorithm:

```
extend :: (Num w, Ord w, Ord n) => w -> n -> Summary w n -> Summary w n
extend w n s = answer where
    answer = s
        { endingHere = max (0, []) ((Sum w, [n]) <> endingHere s)
        , endingAnywhere = max (endingHere answer) (endingAnywhere s)
        }
```

This function slots into our flood-fill algorithm nicely to find candidate paths starting from a particular node:

```
findCandidates :: (Num w, Ord w, Ord n) => Tree w n -> n -> [Summary w n]
findCandidates t n = findLeaves t n >>= flood extend emptySummary t
```

The top-level function just does the flood-fill and picks the maximum candidate. (Ties are broken arbitrarily, as they were in `extend`.)

```
maximalPath :: (Num w, Ord w, Ord n) => Tree w n -> n -> WeightedPath w n
maximalPath t n = maximum . map endingAnywhere $ findCandidates t n
```

Let's see it run. We'll define a very simple sample tree: it's a star-shaped tree, with node `0` at its center and nodes `1` through `5` each connected to the central hub. The center has weight `-1`, and the leaves are weighted `1` through `5` according to which node they are.

```
sampleTree :: Tree Int Int
sampleTree 0 = (-1, [1..5])
sampleTree n = (n, [0])
```

In ghci, we can find now find the maximal path by providing a tree and any node in the tree:

```
> maximalPath sampleTree 0
(Sum {getSum = 8},[5,0,4])
```

...which says that the largest sum is `8`, and it can be achieved by traveling the path from outer node 5 to the hub node 0, then outward to node 4.

Comment: Please detail your answer. Can you give some more examples? :p

Comment: @A.S.H I'd be happy to. What examples would you like to see?

Comment: Can this algorithm handle the *tree of Christmas* ? (just joking)

Comment: I believe that there is indeed a cheaper dynamic programming solution, and I have added an answer attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

At every node of the tree compute:

1) The path with largest sum arising from any descendant of that node to that node.

2) The path with largest sum that can be found in the sub-tree rooted at that node.

Both of these can be computed using values computed at the children of that node.

In case (1) the answer is either the 0 length path starting and stopping at that node, or the sum of the value at that node and the largest (1) value at any child.

In case (2) the answer is either the sum of the two largest (1) values for that node, minus the value at that node, or the largest (2) value from any child.

The value you are looking for is the (2) value at the root, and you can add additional book-keeping to work out the path involved.

The cost here is basically the cost to recursively traverse the tree, doing most of the work as you return from a depth first search, so I think it is O(n)